# How Can I Keep Certain Controls From Updating In An UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an `UpdatePanel` with many objects within. How can I prevent some of them from reloading when the panel is refreshed? Is there a tag to make this happen, to sort of "isolate" some elements from the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use multiple `UpdatePanels` in your layout so that you can effectively group what needs to be grouped. Then you need to make sure that the `UpdatePanels` are set to `Conditional` so that you can control whether they will asyncpostback when other `UpdatePanels` asyncpostback.

**Edit**: Here is a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx) that demonstrates some of this functionality